# Logistic regression: Why protective factor become risk factor?

Tags: statistics

I used logistic analysis to build a predictive model for liver toxicity after radiotherapy. I got:

(1+e^(-S))^(-1)
S = 0.00337 ∙ normal liver volume - 0.00579 ∙ VS10 + 2.88 ∙ preCP - 2.51; normal liver volume, OR = 1.003 (95% CI, 1.000-1.007), p = 0.047; VS10, OR = 0.994 (95% CI, 0.991-0.998), p = 0.002; preCP, OR = 17.883 (95% CI, 3.235-98.848), p = 0.001.

The normal liver tissue should be the protective factor in clinical practice. Here its OR is greater than 1. Why? (The outcome setting was right.)